# How to modify keyframe A and B via Python

Tags: python, scripting, tracking

I'm stuck trying to access the Keyframe A and B options through Blender's Python API. To give you a better idea, here's a screenshot of the options I'm talking about::[image]

I've tried a few things to get to them but haven't had any luck. For example, I tried using Blender tooltips, but the text keeps getting cut off, no matter how wide I make the window. Here's what I'm seeing:

**bpy.data.movieclips["0001.png"] ... keyframe_a**.

[image]

I also tried selecting the value and hitting enter to see if it would show up in the info window. I even tried changing the number, but both actions gave me the same result:

**bpy.data.movieclips["0001.png"].(null) = 30**

**bpy.data.movieclips["0001.png"].(null) = 59**

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on `Keyframe A` and select `Edit Source`

[image]

You will get this class in the text editor.

```
class CLIP_PT_tools_solve(CLIP_PT_tracking_panel, Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'CLIP_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_label = "Solve"
    bl_category = "Solve"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False

        clip = context.space_data.clip
        tracking = clip.tracking
        settings = tracking.settings
        tracking_object = tracking.objects.active
        camera = clip.tracking.camera

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(settings, "use_tripod_solver", text="Tripod")
        col = layout.column()
        col.active = not settings.use_tripod_solver
        col.prop(settings, "use_keyframe_selection", text="Keyframe")

        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.active = (not settings.use_tripod_solver and
                      not settings.use_keyframe_selection)
        col.prop(tracking_object, "keyframe_a")
        col.prop(tracking_object, "keyframe_b")

        col = layout.column(heading="Refine", align=True)
        col.active = tracking_object.is_camera
        col.prop(settings, "refine_intrinsics_focal_length", text="Focal Length")
        col.prop(settings, "refine_intrinsics_principal_point", text="Optical Center")

        col.prop(settings, "refine_intrinsics_radial_distortion", text="Radial Distortion")

        row = col.row()
        row.active = (camera.distortion_model == 'BROWN')
        row.prop(settings, "refine_intrinsics_tangential_distortion", text="Tangential Distortion")

        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.scale_y = 2.0

        col.operator("clip.solve_camera",
                     text="Solve Camera Motion" if tracking_object.is_camera
                     else "Solve Object Motion")
```

Now the `keyframe_a` and `keyframe_a` props has the data of `tracking_object`

```
clip = context.space_data.clip
tracking = clip.tracking
tracking_object = tracking.objects.active

col.prop(tracking_object, "keyframe_a")
col.prop(tracking_object, "keyframe_b")
```

To modify `Keyframe A` and `Keyframe B`, try this in the console.

```
# replace `footage.mp4` with your movieclip name
D.movieclips['footage.mp4'].tracking.objects.active.keyframe_a = 5
D.movieclips['footage.mp4'].tracking.objects.active.keyframe_b = 10
```